# Ionic 4, el input FILE no funciona en IOS para cargar imágenes y pdf

Tags: ionic, ios, ionic4

Tengo una aplicación con ionic 4, en la que en un módulo necesito poder subir imágenes o archivos pdf para poder generar un base64.

Estoy usando un input file y esto funciona bien en Android, la imagen o el pdf se carga y se genera el base64 que envío en mi solicitud, pero en IOS no funciona, no carga la imagen.

Entonces tengo la entrada en mi componente.

```
  <input 
    *ngIf="config.file"
    type="file" 
    (change)="getErrors($event)" 
    class="file"
  >
```

y la función `getErrors` que es donde obtengo el file tiene esto

```
getErrors(val)
  {
    if(this.config.file)
    {
      this.config.filePath   = val.path[0].files[0];
      this.config.fileType   = val.path[0].files[0].type;
      this.config.fileExt    = val.path[0].files[0].name.substring(val.path[0].files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
      this.config.value      = val.path[0].files[0].name;

      toBase64(val.path[0].files[0])
      .then((resolve) => {
        this.config.fileBase64 = resolve.split("base64,")[1];
      })

    }

    if(this.config['callback'])
    {
      this.Handler.emit();
    }

    controllerErrors(this.config.validations, val);
    serverError(this.config.validations);
  }
```

Como digo esto funciona perfecto en Android, pero no en IOS y no sé por qué, tengo muy poca experiencia en IOS y no sé si esta tarea está siendo bloqueada por algo específico.

Answer (score 1):

Debes agregar los permisos de acceso a las fotos para que el usuario autorice al momento de abrir tu App.
Lo agregas en el archivo `.plist` de Xcode haciendo click en el símbolo `+` de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si abres el archivo `.plist` como código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes agregar el siguiente código:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Aquí una descripción.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Otra descripción.</string>
```